# Remix IDE unable to load 3rd party library

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, openzeppelin

While trying to import

> openZeppelin

library in remix IDE (the online version), it always return this error

> Contract not found

and this is how I tried to import it

```
import "github/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/math/SafeMath. sol";
```

and it doesn't work and i tried this as well

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

and it still didn't work as well

How do I import it correctly

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because of compiler version.
This will not work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

This will work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v2.5.0/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
```

Comment: Can I port 0.4.24 codes to the 0.5.0?

Comment: Far as I know then it isn't possible to automatically migrate code and you would need to make changes accordingly to https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/050-breaking-changes.html# I think it is easier to use different SafeMath.sol https://github.com/ConsenSysMesh/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol